# Azure REST API - $filter param for time delta throws ProviderError

Tags: azure, api, azure-resource-manager

We are facing issues with the Azure API endpoint for fetching security alerts based on given time filter.

Azure API Documentation Link and screenshot for the API section,
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/listbyresourcegroup

[Screenshot - API Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3eW6.png)

We encountered the following error while hitting the endpoint with the required params and Bearer access token.

**Error Details:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ProviderError",
        "message": "Resource provider 'Microsoft.Security' failed to return collection response for type 'alerts'."
    }
}
```

**Endpoint URL:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Security/alerts?api-version={version}}&$filter=properties.reportedTimeUtc eq '2019-07-06T08:00:51.8801218Z'
```

NOTE:
The URL gives response without specifying the time “filter” , but when using filter as one of the params, we get the above mentioned error.

The param value used:  `$filter = properties.reportedTimeUtc eq '2019-07-06T08:00:51.8801218Z'`

[Screenshot - filter param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5hwo.png)

Could anyone help in the resolution of this issue? Let me know for any additional details/clarifications. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387673/odata-date-greater-than-filter) SO question. Try the suggested formats mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter reportedTimeUtc , you can refer to the following method:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Security/alerts?$filter=Properties/ReportedTimeUtc eq 2019-05-18T12:20:13.3196284Z&api-version=2019-01-01
```

Just note the filter value format: **Properties/ReportedTimeUtc eq 2019-05-18T12:20:13.3196284Z**
And the first letter must be in Uppercase.

Result:

[image]